# ¿Cómo convertir un arreglo unimensional en uno bidimensional?

Tags: c#

Estoy trabajando con un array tipo string de 2 columnas x 30 filas, el problema es que en realidad los strings de la columna 1 y 2 están "unidos" solo los separa un carácter "|" (ya que está información proviene de un XML)
en realidad  es el resultado de una consulta a través de un *Web Service SOAP*.

Quiero convertir este array a uno bidimensional .. dónde la columna 1 y 2 estén
separadas pero que sigan perteneciendo a la misma fila.
Ejemplo el objeto que me devuelve la consulta al SOAP se lo asigné a un Array y me permite recorrerlo así:

```
Arr[0]= 1|Fernando Gómez 
Arr[1]= 2|Luis Pérez
```

(observen que este Array se comporta mas como un arreglo unidimensional) Y lo que necesito y como debería quedar es así:

```
Arr[0,0] = 1 
Arr[0,1] = Fernando Gomez
Arr[1,0]= 2
Arr[1,1]= Luis Perez
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda

Comment: Pon lo que has intentado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa la función split, que divide un array en varias columnas. Luego recorres el array nuevo con un foreach para ver si los datos te los dividió bien o debuggeas.

```
string[30][2] arraynuevo; //este sería el array bidimensional que tu quieres obtener
for(fila=0,fila<=29,fila++){
   string[] arrayauxiliar = Arr[fila].split('|'); //Arr seria el array que te devuelve el servicio SOAP
   arraynuevo[fila][0] = arrayauxiliar[0][0];
   arraynuevo[fila][1] = arrayauxiliar[0][1];
}
```

Prueba con este código, y revisa que el arraynuevo tiene los datos correctos como los quieres.

Comment: Gran idea , mil gracias... estoy resolviendo aun.

Answer (score 1):

Yo te recomiendo usar el tipo de dato **Dictionary<key, value>**. Un diccionario es una estructura de datos que permite almacenar información, a través de una **estructura llave-valor**. La llave es un valor único que no puede repetirse el cual está asociado a un valor específico.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dicc = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var a in array)
{
     var llaveValor = a.Split('|');

     dicc.Add(llaveValor [0], llaveValor [1]);       
}
```

Aquí se declara la **variable dicc** de tipo **Dictionary<string, string>**, donde tanto la llave como el valor serán de tipo string(pero pueden ser de cualquier tipo). Después recorremos con un **ciclo foreach** el arreglo original y utilizamos el **método Split** el cual nos permite separar una cadena por el caracter que le digamos, en este caso **'|'**, el **método Split** devuelve un arreglo con todas las palabras que fueron separadas teniendo en cuenta el caracter **'|'**. Posteriormente añadimos al diccionario la posición **0** y la posición **1** del arreglo obtenido. La posición **0** sería la llave y la posición **1** el valor.

En el ejemplo que pones sería:

```
llave = 1; valor = Fernando Gomez
```

Para recorrer un diccionario harías:

```
foreach( var d in dicc)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Llave = {0}, Valor = {1}", d.Key, d.Value);        
}
```

Donde recorres el diccionario y vas imprimiendo por cada elemento del mismo su llave y su valor.

Usar diccionarios te va a facilitar mucho el trabajo, te sugiero que busques más información en Internet.

Comment: Mil gracias entre los dos comentarios aprendí mucho y estoy haciéndolo de las dos maneras.

Comment: @FernandoSaldarriagaGomez no olvides darle un voto positivo a las respuestas que te fueron útiles y aceptar la que más te gusto y/o aporto, gracias